# While doesn't count to the last element of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have some lines of data on a table as shown below :

```
 +-------------------+-------+
 | criteria          | value |
 +-------------------+-------+
 | Pengalaman Kerja  |     4 |
 | Pendidikan        |     3 |
 | Usia              |     5 |
 | Status Perkawinan |     2 |
 | Alamat            |     6 |
 | Pengalaman Kerja  |     3 |
 | Pendidikan        |     1 |
 | Usia              |     4 |
 | Status Perkawinan |     2 |
 | Alamat            |     1 |
 +-------------------+-------+
 10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried to fetch them all in PHP using `fetch_object()` and then convert the returned data into arrays and sum the values of each criteria listed on the table.
example : `Pengalaman kerja` has two values (4 and 3) so the result for `Pengalaman Kerja` array will be 7.

```
 $result      = $db->query($sql);
 $value       = array();

 while($row=$result->fetch_object()){

 if(!isset($value[$row->criteria]){
   $value[$row->criteria] = 0;
 })

   $value[$row->criteria] += $row->value;

   var_dump($value);
 }
```

When I ran `var_dump` to `$value` (which is now contains summed value of each criteria) it showed me :

```
 array(5) {
   ["Pengalaman Kerja"]=>
   int(7)
   ["Pendidikan"]=>
   int(4)
   ["Usia"]=>
   int(9)
   ["Status Perkawinan"]=>
   int(4)
   ["Alamat"]=>
   int(6)
 }
```

`Pengalaman kerja` is correct because 4 + 3 = 7
`Pendidikan` is correct because 3 + 1 = 4
`Usia` is correct because 5 + 4 = 9
`Status Perkawinan` is correct because 2 + 2 = 4
And the wrong thing is `Alamat` showing 6 that it should be 7 because 6 + 1 = 7

I'm sure it was because one of `Alamat` record was on the last of lines and the `while()` function didn't count until the last of lines.
`While()` function only counted to the last - 1

How can I solve this problem so `Alamat` shows 7 as it is suppossed to show ?

Answer (score 1):

Why even bother doing this in PHP? If you just want the sum of all rows grouped by `criteria` then do it with a simple MySQL query?

```
SELECT criteria, SUM(value) AS total FROM table GROUP BY criteria
```

**EDIT:** If you insist on doing it your way then aside from a couple of typos in your code, which would usually cause runtime errors, your code should work as expected. When I run it against a table with the exact same data I get the expected results.

BTW, [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) has no method called `fetch_object` (this is the name of the helper function) so if you want to use a method to fetch the query results as an object for a PDOStatement you have to use the proper name which is [fetchObject()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php).

**PHP**

```
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM test");
$value = array();

while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {
    if (!isset($value[$row->criteria])) {
        $value[$row->criteria] = 0;
    }
    $value[$row->criteria] += $row->value;
}
var_dump($value);
```

**Results**

```
array (size=5)
  'Pengalaman Kerja' => int 7
  'Pendidikan' => int 4
  'Usia' => int 9
  'Status Perkawinan' => int 4
  'Alamat' => int 7
```

Comment: Actually, I had done using SQL Query too before asking this question. Just looking for new ways :)

Comment: Updated my answer to include further info.

Comment: could you please point me to what has been going wrong in my code? Your code written above look similar to mine. There's no difference

Comment: I've commented in my post on everything that was changed. Basically the only difference is in a typo and using `fetchObject` instead of `fetch_object`. The latter should have actually caused a runtime error.

Comment: Okay. It's solved. It was a stupid mistake. I put var_dump before $nilai_kuadrat[$row->criteria] += $row->value;

Comment: Thanks, anyway, bro.. You helped me a lot :)